# Caching image so it does not reload on reloadData call - AFNetworking 2.0 setImageWithUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking-2

There are a few questions on stack overflow around this topic but I can't find a solution.

Each tableview cell in my tableview has an imageview which is loaded from a url.

The images load fine but whenever I'm calling reloadData the images are once again loaded creating a flickering effect. In cellForRowAtIndexPath I set the image in prepareForReuse to a blank image and so it flickers here too.

I'm aware I need to cache the image but how do I go about this? Do I need to store my own cached images and update this as and when the underlying data changes? Does AFNetworking provide this by default?

I've tried NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad - it does not seem to work.

```
[cell.recipientProfilePic setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[user.photos objectAtIndex:0]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:2300] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_image_load"] 
  success:nil
  failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool, you can install it with Cocoapods:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

It handles caching and loading images for `UIImageView` via URL with `sd_imageWithURL:` Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I'd rather not install another library for this unless I have to. Do you know if this is possible using AFNetworking?

Comment: Well AFNetworking, SDWebImage, and GPUImage are the three libraries that most developers use to handle images in iOS. If you really don't want to use another library, then you could just store the downloaded image onto disk and store a dictionary of URLs onto NSUserDefaults. But this seems like so much work since SDWebImage handles caching and prefetching for you.